# sound wave sawtooth in c

Tags: c, audio, wav

I'm trying to generate sawtooth wave in c.
I'm so close to the end of my work but I have problem which must be resolved.
I attached clode below.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tgmath.h>

/******************************
*  Magic file format strings. *
******************************/
const char fChunkID[]     = {'R', 'I', 'F', 'F'};
const char fFormat[]      = {'W', 'A', 'V', 'E'};
const char fSubchunk1ID[] = {'f', 'm', 't', ' '};
const char fSubchunk2ID[] = {'d', 'a', 't', 'a'};

/********************************
* WriteWavePCM() configuration: *
* - 2 channels,                 *
* - frequency 44100 Hz.         *
********************************/
const unsigned short N_CHANNELS = 2;
const unsigned int SAMPLE_RATE = 48000;
const unsigned short BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;

bool WriteWavePCM(short* sound, size_t pairAmount, char* fileName){
    const static unsigned int fSubchunk1Size = 16;
    const static unsigned short fAudioFormat = 1;
    const static unsigned short fBitsPerSample = 16;

    unsigned int fByteRate = SAMPLE_RATE * N_CHANNELS * fBitsPerSample / BITS_PER_BYTE;

    unsigned short fBlockAlign = N_CHANNELS * fBitsPerSample / BITS_PER_BYTE;
    unsigned int fSubchunk2Size;
    unsigned int fChunkSize;

    FILE* fout;
    size_t ws;

    if (!sound || !fileName || !(fout = fopen( fileName, "w" ))) return false;

    fSubchunk2Size = pairAmount * N_CHANNELS * fBitsPerSample / BITS_PER_BYTE;
    fChunkSize = 36 + fSubchunk2Size;

    // Writing the RIFF header:
    fwrite(&fChunkID, 1, sizeof(fChunkID),      fout);
    fwrite(&fChunkSize,  sizeof(fChunkSize), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&fFormat, 1,  sizeof(fFormat),       fout);

    // "fmt" chunk:
    fwrite(&fSubchunk1ID, 1, sizeof(fSubchunk1ID),      fout);
    fwrite(&fSubchunk1Size,  sizeof(fSubchunk1Size), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&fAudioFormat,    sizeof(fAudioFormat),   1, fout);
    fwrite(&N_CHANNELS,      sizeof(N_CHANNELS),     1, fout);
    fwrite(&SAMPLE_RATE,     sizeof(SAMPLE_RATE),    1, fout);
    fwrite(&fByteRate,       sizeof(fByteRate),      1, fout);
    fwrite(&fBlockAlign,     sizeof(fBlockAlign),    1, fout);
    fwrite(&fBitsPerSample,  sizeof(fBitsPerSample), 1, fout);

    /* "data" chunk: */
    fwrite(&fSubchunk2ID, 1, sizeof(fSubchunk2ID),      fout);
    fwrite(&fSubchunk2Size,  sizeof(fSubchunk2Size), 1, fout);

    /* sound data: */
    ws = fwrite(sound, sizeof(short), pairAmount * N_CHANNELS, fout);
    fclose(fout);
    return true;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////

const unsigned int N_SAMPLE_PAIRS = 50000;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    short* sound;
    int i;
    int j;
    bool status;
    char* file_name;
    int l; // dodane

    sound = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N_SAMPLE_PAIRS * N_CHANNELS );

    if (!sound)
    {
        puts("Could not allocate space for the sound data.");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int amplitude = 10000;
    int frequency = 80;
    short record = 0;
    short waveNumber = 1;
    int samplesPerWavelength = SAMPLE_RATE / (frequency/N_CHANNELS);
    int soundLen = 10 * samplesPerWavelength;
    int ampStep = (int)((amplitude*2)/(int)samplesPerWavelength);
    short step = 5*samplesPerWavelength;
    short muteRate = amplitude/(soundLen/samplesPerWavelength);
    int totalSamplesWritten = 0;
    int tempSample =0;

    for (i=0, j=0; i<N_SAMPLE_PAIRS*N_CHANNELS; i+=2, j++) {
        ampStep = (int)((amplitude*2)/(int)samplesPerWavelength);
        tempSample = (int)((totalSamplesWritten%samplesPerWavelength)*ampStep);
        sound[i] = tempSample;
        sound[i+1] = tempSample;
        totalSamplesWritten++;
    }


    file_name = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "Default2.wav";
    status = WriteWavePCM(sound, N_SAMPLE_PAIRS, file_name);


    free(sound);

    if (status)
    {
        printf("Discotheque is ready in \"%s\"\n", file_name);
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Something seems to have gone wrong." );
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my result. There is sawtooth but with strange behavior. I don't know why this is there. I checked my array of samples and everything look good.

[image]

Can someone help me? I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. I checked it in 2 different programs: audiocity and wavepadaudio and in both of then, this behavior exist. So i'm problem with my code for sure. Help me please.

[image]

Comment: Seems to work for me...  How are you compiling / running it?  Can you see how many samples seem corrupt?

Comment: I notice you have `int soundLen = 10 * samplesPerWavelength;` and 3 lines further on is `soundLen / samplesPerWavelength` which we can see is `10`. The integer arithmetic seems to work exactly here but are there other examples of the same thing that do not?

Comment: I'm using codeblock to compile it. If you printf tempSample in the loop, you can see that they are not corrupted. Can you show me how it look after you compile ?

Comment: I added new photo

Comment: @Sekru if you post your output wav file somewhere I'll take a look at it.

Comment: https://ufile.io/n11ny here you can download wav

Comment: I confirm that the glitch in each cycle of that download can be seen in Audacity.

Comment: Since you're using 16bit pcm maybe you should have `tempSample` as a short

Comment: MSVC compilation shows the same glitch, but note two compiler warnings: (a) '=': incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'short *' and (b) '<': signed/unsigned mismatch.

Comment: wav is a simple format. Perhaps you can inspect the file directly with a hexeditor? That eliminates weird audio software issues.

Comment: Are you compiling with the `-Wall` flag? You should be: it will warn you about a large number of subtle issues that may cause problems.

Comment: You appear to be relying to some extent on specific representations of your integer types -- both size and byte order.  I'm uncertain whether your assumptions turn out to match the WAV format when compiled with your particular compiler.  Robust code would be a lot more careful about things like this.

Comment: mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2 -std=c99  -c D:\smiw\main\main.c -o obj\Release\main.o I have got only warnings about not used vars

Comment: The first warning is from line 79 where you are casting the pointer returned by `malloc` to `int*` and assigning that to `short*` but you should not cast the return value of `malloc` anyway. The second warning is on line 99 and concerns the loop iteration control variable. I don't see how either of these will cause the glitch, but they should be dealt with anyway.

Comment: I resolved each warning but there is still the same issue

Comment: Time to put this in a debugger.  I would add a condition to the loop checking `if(tempSample > 25000) printf("wrong\n");` and put a breakpoint there to examine

Comment: Why 25000 ? Can you explain ?

Comment: I've downloaded and run your program. And I've downloaded the `.wav` file _you_ generated. The size of the file when _I_ run the program is: 200044 but _your_ version is 201388. Could be just math roundoff error in your sound sample loop, but I thought I'd mention it. FYI, I'm using linux

Comment: 25000, @Sekru, because in your glitchy result, only the glitches have amplitude that high.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I looked at the file dump (MSVC compilation) I noticed some `0D 0A` data pairs. I then changed this

```
fout = fopen( fileName, "w" )
```

to this specifing a binary file

```
fout = fopen( fileName, "wb" )
```

and now the glitch has gone.

Note that

> If `t`or `b` is not given in `mode`, the default translation mode is
>   defined by the global variable `_fmode`.

So the default translation mode must have been "text".

Comment: That explains *everything*.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some screen captures of the output I get.  Seems fine to me.

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.4.0-1.i686/src/gcc-5.4.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.4.0-1.i686/src/
gcc-5.4.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/h
tml -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=
/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_ate
xit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++
--enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enab
le-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-
ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-
libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC)

uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW DE-E03895 2.8.0(0.309/5/3) 2017-04-01 20:42 i686 Cygwin

[image: Here it is]

[image: Zoomed in]

Here's a screen shot of the corrupted samples in your output;

[image]

Comment: So your answer is "works for me"?  Fair enough, but I'm sure the OP would appreciate some insight into where it may be breaking for them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger He asked "Can you show me how it look after you compile ?" and the only way I know how to post an image was in an answer.

Comment: Thank, now I know that something is wrong with my compilator or outputfile. Closer to resolve issue

Comment: The blowup of the glitch is nice.  It's particularly suspicious that although the glitches have the same general shape in each channel, they are not exactly the same.  Amplitudes and phases both differ somewhat.