# Writing a text-viewing program using C

Tags: c

Chapter **13. File Input/Output** of the textbook *C Primer Plus*, 6th edition, by Stephen Prata, says the following:

> To bring some regularity to the handling of text files, C provides two ways of accessing a file: binary mode and text mode. In the binary mode, each and every byte of the file is accessible to a program. In the text mode, however, what the program sees can differ from what is in the file. With the text view, the local environment’s representation of such things as the end of a line or end-of-file are mapped to the C view when a file is read. Similarly, the C view is mapped to the local representation of output. For example, a C program compiled on an older Macintosh and using text mode would convert \r to \n when reading a file in text mode and convert \n to \r when writing to a file. Or a C text-mode program compiled on an MS-DOS platform would convert \r\n to \n when reading from a file and convert \n to \r\n when writing to a file. Text-mode programs written for other environments make similar adjustments.
>
> You aren’t restricted to using only the text view for a text file. You can also use the binary view of the same file. If you do for an old MS-DOS text file, your program sees both the \r and the \n characters in the file; no mapping takes place. (Figure 13.1 illustrates this with some nautical text.) If you want to write a text-viewing program that works for, say, old Mac formats, MS-DOS formats, and Unix/Linux formats, you would use binary mode so that the program could determine the actual file contents and act accordingly.
> [image]

The reasoning for using binary mode if writing a text-viewing program makes no sense to me. If our goal is to write a text-viewing program, if C's text view of a file automatically maps the binary values (the local environment's representation) to text view (regardless of whether the file is an MS-DOS text file, an old Mac text file, or something else), then why is it of any importance that we use the binary view? If I'm understanding this correctly, all of the mapping between the local environment's binary view and C's text view is done automatically, so why wouldn't we just use text view rather than binary view? The author seems to imply that there is some important difference here that means that we should use binary view, but I don't see it. Perhaps there is some nuance that I'm missing here.

Comment: You are correct. But . . . sometimes the file encoding is just a number. For example, see [sound wave sawtooth in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53506849/2472827).

Comment: Because if you get a Unix file on Windows, or a Windows file on a Mac, or... (which happens all the time BTW) the text opening mode will be confusing at best, and totally break things at worst. And the book is saying that much. *If you want to write a text-viewing program that works for, say, old Mac formats, MS-DOS formats, **and** Unix/Linux formats...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a file in text mode, it assumes the file format is appropriate for the operating system you're running the program on.

But suppose you're running the program on Unix, but want to write a program that creates a file for Windows. If it writes the file in text mode, it will use `\n` as the newline characters, but Windows expects `\r\n`.

So your program should instead open the file in binary mode, and write `\r\n` explicitly.

This is a pretty unusual thing to do, and very few applications do this. Normally programs assume that they're working with files appropriate for the current OS. We use separate format conversion programs when transfering files between operating systems. For instance, you can use `dos2unix` on Linux to remove the `\r` characters from a text file that was copied from Windows.

Comment: *This is a pretty unusual thing to do* not really. Most text editors do that, source control systems do that, etc. Otherwise it would be a real pain in the neck to work in a heterogeneous environment.

Comment: @n.m. I think lots of them simply ignore `\r` at the end of the line; in many contexts (e.g. compilers) it's simply insignificant whitespaces. Some text editors will try to guess the file format and adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Those `\r` characters in a DOS text file are part of the file size.
If one loads a line (or the entire file) *filtered by a driver stripping out `\r'*, then the byte count loaded will be less than the file system's report of the file's byte count...

A C programmer needs to be aware of the fact.

Here's a DOS file (with its \r\n characters made explicit). It's 5 duplicate lines.

```
0123456789\r\n0123456789\r\n0123456789\r\n0123456789\r\n0123456789\r\n
```

and here's a program that loads those 5 * (10+2) bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[100];

    fp = fopen( "foo.txt", "rb" );
    /* omitting test */
    printf( "%zu bytes\n", fread( buf, sizeof buf[0], sizeof buf, fp ) );
    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
    printf( "%zu bytes\n", ftell( fp ) );
    fclose( fp );

    fp = fopen( "foo.txt", "rt" );
    /* omitting test */
    printf( "%zu bytes\n", fread( buf, sizeof buf[0], sizeof buf, fp ) );
    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
    printf( "%zu bytes\n", ftell( fp ) );
    fclose( fp );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
60 bytes
60 bytes
55 bytes
60 bytes
```

The programmer needs to be aware of why 55 is not 60 (in this example).